# best db for delphi and large databases

Tags: delphi, server, rdbms

Using Delphi XE2: I have used AbsoluteDB for years with good success for smallish needs, but it does not scale well to large datasets.  I need recommendations for a DB engine for the following conditions:

- Large (multi-gigabyte) dataset, few tables with lots of small records.  This is industrial-equipment historical data; most tables have new records written once a minute with a device ID, date, time and status; a couple tables have these records w/ a single data point per record, three others have 10 to 28 data points per record depending on the device type.  One of the single-data-point tables adds events asynchronously and might have a dozen or more entries per minute.  All of this has to be kept available for up to a year.  Data is usually accessed by device ID(s) and date window.
- Multi-user.  A system service retrieves the data from the devices, but the trending display is a separate application and may be on a separate computer.
- Fast.  Able to pull any 48-hour cluster of data in at most a half-dozen seconds.
- Not embedded.
- Single-file if possible.  Critical that backups and restores can by done programatically.  Replication support would be nice but not required.
- Can be integrated into our existing InstallAware packages, without user intervention in the install process.
- Critical: no per-install licenses.  I'm fine with buying per-seat developer licenses, but we're an industrial-equipment company, not a software company - we're not set up for keeping track of that sort of thing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SO guidelines state clearly that questions that ask for recommendations are off-topic here. See the [help/on-topic], particularly the numbered list on that page.

Comment: @MajidTaheri: Even anything can be useful. Answering this sort of off-topic question in any way (including in comments) simply encourages other off-topic questions, and there is no point in doing so.

Comment: Software recommendations can go to [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: If you're the same Steve Sneed as used regularly to support TurboPower's section on CIS's PCVenB, you'll have noticed the difference between here and there, in terms of reception.  I'm afraid SO isn't the ideal forum for this sort of topic, but the EMB newsgroups are still good, assuming you manage to catch their server in one of its 'up' moments.

Comment: OK, sorry for the mis-post.  And yes, Martyn, I'm that Steve Sneed. Long ago in a galaxy far far away, eh? :)

Answer (score 3):

I would use

- either [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) (more proven than MySQL for such huge data)
- or [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/)

The main criteria is what you would do with the data. And you did not say much about that. Would you do individual queries by data point? Would you need to do aggregates (sum/average...) over data points per type? If "Data is usually accessed by device ID(s) and date window", then I would perhaps not store the data in individual rows, one row per data point, but gather data within "[aggregates](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html)", i.e. objects or arrays stored in a "document" column.

You may store those aggregates as BLOB, but it may be not efficient. Both *PostgreSQL* and *MongoDB* have powerful objects and arrays functions, including indexes within the documents.

Don't start from the DB, but start from your logic: which data are you gathering? how is it acquired? how is it later on accessed? Then design high level objects, and let your DB store your objects in an efficient way.

Also consider the [CQRS pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html): it is a good idea to store your data in several places, in several layouts, and make a clear distinction between writes (Commands) and reads (Queries). For instance, you may send all individual data points in a database, but gather the information, in a ready-to-use form, in other databases. Don't hesitate to duplicate the data! Don't rely on a single-database-centric approach! This is IMHO the key for fast queries - and what all BigData companies do.

Our Open Source [mORMot](http://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#SOURCE) framework is ideal for such process. I'm currently working on a project gathering information in real time from thousands of remote devices connected via Internet (alarm panels, in fact), then consolidating this data in a farm of servers. We use `SQLite3` for local storage on each node (up to some GB), and consolidate the data in `MongoDB` servers. All the logic is written in high-level Delphi objects, and the framework does all the need plumbing (including real-time replication, and callbacks).